# PHP foreach and mysql within

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $q3 = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '$value'";
    $r3 = $wpdb->get_results($q3);
    $Idd = $r3[0]->ID;
    $img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($Idd, 'thumbnail') );
    //echo $value;
    //echo $Idd;
    //echo $img;
    $list .= '<li><img src="'.$img.'"/><br>'.$value.'</li>';
}
```

Using the above, if I `echo $value` my array is printed. if I `echo $Idd` the result instead of several ID's is just a singular and the same goes for `$img`

How can I run the above to work and print out the `$img`'s and `$Idd`

Thanks

Comment: Is the ampersand before $value in the foreach statement supposed to be there?

Comment: @Daniel The `&` is a reference operator - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php. As such, `$value `is a direct reference to the entry in `$array`, not a copy of it.

Comment: Cool thanks for letting me know, not familiar with those!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is loading the first value of the result set and only using it.

If you need to display all the values, then you will need to loop over the results.

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $q3 = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '$value'";
    $r3 = $wpdb->get_results($q3);
    foreach ($r3 as $imgRes)
    {
      $Idd = $imgRes->ID;
      $img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($Idd, 'thumbnail') );
      $list .= '<li><img src="'.$img.'"/><br>'.$value.'</li>';
    }
}
```